# Sharepoint Online DocumentSharing API

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-2013, preview, office365, office365-apps

trying to share a file with external users via the API, our in-house app will upload the file to sharepoint, return the view only link and we can then send that link to external users avoiding emails etc.

Is this possible with .NET C#?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. with the [SharePoint client object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx), your application can: Upload the document to the document list, and set the permission for that item, then return the link to external user.